# Не работает foreach

Tags: java

```
public class EtazhDoma implements Etazh {
    private Pomeshenie[] hati;
@Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new Iterator() {
            int current = 0;
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return current != hati.length;
            }

            @Override
            public Pomeshenie next() {
                return hati[current++];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Интерфейс имеет метод `public Iterator iterator()` и расширяет `Iterable`.
PS.: Не обращайте внимание на названия :-))

Проблема: В `foreach` требует замены `Pomeshenie` на `Object`

```
for (Pomeshenie hata: etazh) {

    }
```

Comment: ах, да используй  code style, а то читать твой код неприятно

Answer (score 4):

```
Interface Iterable<E>
```

интерфейс использует дженерик, вам надо это указать.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html

```
public class EtazhDoma implements Etazh, Iterable<Pomeshenie>
```

Comment: Может тогда Iterable?

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо, указал дженерик у Iterable и у метода iterator

Comment: ну да Iterable, но суть та же =) посмотрел первое, что гугл выдал